# Can the parameter of a function be used as a placeholder for global variables

Tags: python, variables, global

I am working on a little Game.
I am trying to build a switch function which is just supposed to change a global variable form False to True. This way I want to controll the  progress of the player.
I'v tried using the parameter of the function as a placeholder for any global variable that I want to switch but it wont work.

Changing a single global variable by writing in its specific name into the funktion works fine. 
I know that this change will only last until the programm is closed but I do not care about that at the moment.
All i want now is not to write a new function for every single global variable I want to switch.

```
v = False
y = False 
z = False

def switch(x):
    global x
    x = True
```

does not work

Comment: Simply `... = True` is arguably so simple that it doesn't warrant a function if that's all it's doing. There's no straightforward way to do what you want that I know of. You could mess with `globals`, but that would just lead to unnecessary messes. I think you should rethink your design.

Comment: No: From running your code: `SyntaxError: name 'x' is parameter and global`. Besides, you should avoid using global variables whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what dictionaries are for:

```
my_vars = dict( x=False, y=False, z=False )

def switch(x):
    global my_vars
    my_vars[x] = True
```

But take the comments to your question to heart.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to one of the many sites for python and pygame help before going here with such a simple question.

That being said, just define the variable earlier and then set it to true later using a dict

```
myVars = {
'x': False
'y': 'egg'
#some more vars probable
}
#some code
myVars['x'] = True
```